# Databinder.Eval of object inside object

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

How would I retrive the info of an object inside my object using the `Databinder.Eval` method?

The class I'm trying to get the object name from looks like

```
public class Festival
{
    public int id { set; get; }
    public string name { set; get; }
    public DateTime date_start { set; get; }
    public DateTime date_end { set; get; }
    public City city;
}
```

(The city object has an a string called name)

And the code I'm trying to get working is

```
<td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "city.name") %></td>
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the result of your approach? Does it work? What is the datasource exactly, where is the aspx code located?

Comment: No unfourtunatly not, I'm trying to figure out why.

Comment: My question was: what is the result you get? And of course the other questions i've asked.

Comment: My bad, the error I get is: An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: DataBinding: 'h2ASPWebDB.Festival' does not inlclude an option with the name 'city'

Comment: Does the class `City` have a public property `name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a quick hack, try writing a helper method in code behind like:

```
protected string GetCityName(object o)
{
    var c = o as City;
    if(c==null)
        return "Invalid Object";//YOU CAN RETURN EMPTY OR DO SOMETHING ELSE

    return c.name;
}
```

aspx:

```
<%# GetCityName(Eval("city"))%>
```

Or you can have string property in your `Festival` class that returns `City.Name` like:

```
public string CityName{get{return city.name;/*Check for null*/}}
```

Or better still have a view model exposing exactly the properties that you need  and the way you want them.

Comment: try the edited one if this works. It will pass the city.